# Forbid delete if the record is referred from other tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

In SQL Server 2008, how can I forbid the delete (or throw an exception) if the involved record is used from others tables in some foreign keys?

I have set, in the relationship, "on delete -> nothing", but it isn't what I need... I need to stop the delete...

Let's say, if I have the table books and the table authors, and in books I have idAuthor, how can I forbid the delete of an author, if I have at least one book written by him?

Comment: That should be default. If you want to delete automatically all  books of that author you have to specify `cascade delete` in the FK-relation. Of yourse you have to create that relation first. Have you saved it?

Comment: yes, I don't know why, it deletes anyway...  I mean, I if set on delete -> nothing, it deletes authors without edit books...

Comment: I don't know the option "delete -> nothing", where are you setting it? You have following options: 1. No Action 2. Cascade 3. Set Null 4. Set Default. "No Action" means error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server use `no action`:

```
alter table ...
add foreign key
...
on delete no action
```

Other databases use `restrict`:

```
alter table ...
add foreign key
...
on delete restrict
```

In all cases, this option is the default and causes an exception to be thrown if the constraint would be violated by deletion of the parent row.

Answer (score 0):

this happens by default in SQL Server - delete is not allowed for an entity that has foreign key rows (children) referencing it. So you should have "Enforce Foreign Key Constraints" set to YES in the Foreign Key Relation properties, by default.

This setting forces the server to throw an error when constraints are broken.

[partial source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602270/sql-server-what-is-the-benefit-of-using-enforce-foreign-key-constraint-when-i)

PS: I don't know where you are setting the "on delete -> nothing" in SQL Server.

Comment: yes, "No Action" is what you need, this is the default. If this does not work as expected, please add the table definitions to the post (take them from SQL, we need also foreign key definitions).